What's the purpose of std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator?
I'm looking at this example in C++ Reference:
std::array<std::byte, total_nodes * 32> buffer; // enough to fit in all nodes
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbr{buffer.data(), buffer.size()};
std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> pa{&mbr};
std::pmr::list<int> list{pa};
for (int i{}; i != total_nodes; ++i)
    list.push_back(i);

As I understand it, mbr is the one that actually allocates memory and returns void*.
pa is just some kind of type adapter, and returns int*. However, list<int> nodes aren't actually ints. They contain pointers also. So list.push_back() would require pointer casts anyway.
Is there a reason why std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator exists? Why don't std::pmr containers accept std::pmr::memory_resource objects directly?

As far as I can tell (and this is my guess only). std::pmr::memory_resource is suppose to be just a memory allocator (sort of primitive malloc function). On the other hand std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator has construct method which is bale to construct an object in place. So I believe this is kinda "single responsibility principal". In your case you use ints so the constructor is trivial, but could be any user-defined class with non-trivial constructor.

To understand what a polymorphic allocator does, you need to understand what you had to do without a polymorphic allocator.
Normal Allocator
If you want an std::list that allocates from your custom buffer. The standard way is to pass it an allocator in its template arguments std::list<int, MyAllocator>, this allocator can contain a pointer to your buffer (or it can contain the buffer itself, but not recommended).
You cannot use this new list to call the following function
void foo(std::list<int>& l);

because the allocator is embedded into the type system, your list is of a different type.

Polymorphic Allocator
Then comes the polymorphic allocator, it contains a pointer to a polymorphic object, an abstract memory_resource, now you can have the following function.
void foo(std::pmr::list<int>& l)

this function can accept any list that uses a polymorphic allocator, regardless of what the pointed-to memory resource is, it can be the default one, or a monotonic buffer, or a global buffer, or a memory pool, or a disk-mapped buffer, or shared-memory, it is any resource that inherits from the abstract memory_resource.

the downside of a polymorphic allocator is obviously the use of virtual functions on every allocation and deallocation, which is why you would write your own allocator over using the polymorphic allocator if you need every small drop of performance.
syntactically, the lack of a constructor that accepts the resource directly is not really a problem.
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource  b{};
std::pmr::list<int> a{&b};

the standard library doesn't provide a constructor that accepts b directly, but &b is not very bad (the compiler does an implicit conversion for you).

If you write your own allocator, but still use void foo(std::pmr::list<int>& l), I think you'd still have to suffer the same indirection overhead (no free lunch).

@MWB yes, but if you write your own allocator and use a function defined as void foo(std::list<int, MyAllocator>& l) no indirection needed, another alternative is template <typename Alloc> void foo(std::list<int,Alloc>& l) which also has no indirection and the compiler can deduce it, but you then you will use header-only libraries which have their disadvantages (longer compile times and bloated binaries), there will always be compromises

@MWB it depends on what you need from your allocator, avoiding the global allocator has many advantages, the polymorphic allocator is faster than the global, and is a lot faster in multithreaded environments, it also reduces memory fragmentation so your app doesn't slow down as time goes on, and is viable in cases where you cannot call the global allocator (such as embedded devices or time-critical software which needs to have deterministic timings) writing your own allocator could give you better performance, but 90% of the time when you need an allocator the polymorphic one is enough.


require pointer casts anyway

This is a misunderstanding. The Allocator interface allows for rebinding, and this is what would happen. The allocator pa would be rebound to return pointers to list nodes.
So, the question is really when introducing a polymorphic memory allocation facility that returns void*, why allow one to wrap it in something that satisfies the Allocator interface which among other things returns typed pointers? The Allocator interface is much older and automatically supported by standard containers and third party containers. It also is automatically supported by allocator_traits and uses_allocator construction. It also supports constexpr construction.
All of the above would require work to duplicate for memory resources, with limited benefit.
